# use environment variables set in apache v-host to set query param

Tags: apache, vhosts

We have an environment variable CODE set in the Apache vhost

I would like to map incoming requests

```
^/myresource?paramOne=one&paramTwo=two
```

to

```
/some-path-to/my-resource/resource.php?paramOne=one&paramTwo=two&code=theEnvCode
```

In the vhost RewriteRule, is there a way to set the "code" query param to the value of the env var CODE and pass all the other query params from the incoming request?:

```
RewriteRule ^/my-resource /some-path-to/my-resource/resource.php [QSA,L]

Setenv CODE theEnvCode
```

**EDIT**

One possibility is to hardcode the "code" parameter, any other parameter in the request will be appended. But the problem is how to keep in sync 
the code parameter and the environment variable CODE

```
RewriteRule ^/my-resource /some-path-to/my-resource/resource.php?code=theEnvCode [QSA,L]

Setenv CODE theEnvCode
```

A request for `/my-resource?one=two&three=four` will be mapped to `/some-path-to/my-resource/resource.php?code=theEnvCode&one=two&three=four`.

Comment: no, you can't use setenv for this. but mod_rewrite CAN set env vars: `RewriteRule .* - [E=theEnvCode:$1]`-kind of thing.

Comment: thanks @MarcB , is there a way in the RewriteRule to set the "code" param to s hardcoded one but still pass any other query param from the incoming request (the QSA thing)?

Comment: rewriterule is just a regex search/replace, basically. if you want something hardcoded, then hard code it...

Comment: thanks @MarcB , would you mind giving me an example for the case described above? I am still ramping up with apache....

Comment: RewriteRule ^/my-resource /some-path-to/my-resource/resource.php?code=defaultcode [QSA, L]    -- Is this what you mean?

Comment: never done a multi-var assignment in a rule, but if nothing else, you can have multiple rules anyways. `rewriterule .* - [E=hard:coded] rewriterule .*- [E=dynamic:$value]`

Answer (score 0):

Since you rewrite and not redirect to another server, your env variable is still available in the destination URL. Why don't you just retrieve it using `apache_getenv()` in your PHP script? There's no need to pass it as a GET parameter.
See http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-getenv.php